# Не могу найти объяснение работы sql запросов

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть некоторые таблицы в oracle.

Так вот собственно попрос: почему иногда конструкция типа

```
select * from TABLE t where to_char(t.field) = 'somevalue'
```

работает лучше(т.е. быстрее отрабатывает, план запроса лучше, меньше стоимость запроса) чем

```
select * from TABLE t where t.field = 'somevalue'
```

Данное поле проиндексировано. То самое с to_date. 
Такое чувство что индекс по неведомым причинам не подхватывается при "прямых" запросах.
Особенно такое проявляется в сложных запросах, где объединяется несколько таблиц.

Версия oracle: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

Количество данных при выборе не меняется.

План ДО использования to_date на TABLE2

```
select *
  from TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
 where TABLE1.id = TABLE2.TABLEID
   and TABLE1.id = TABLE3.TABLEID
   and TABLE3.DATAFIELD + 1 > trunc(sysdate)
   and TABLE1.DATAFIELD + 1 > trunc(sysdate)
   and ((TABLE2.DATAFIELD = trunc(sysdate)) or (TABLE1.ID = nvl(0, 0)))

-------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2464832983
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name              |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                   |
|   1 |  CONCATENATION                  |                   |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                  |                   |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                 |                   |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                   |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1$           |
|   6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_TABLE1$        |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE2$           |
|   8 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLE2$TABLEID    |
|   9 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN            | TABLE3$TABLEID    |
|  10 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | TABLE3$           |
|  11 |   HASH JOIN                     |                   |
|  12 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL            | TABLE2$           |
|  13 |    NESTED LOOPS                 |                   |
|  14 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                   |
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  15 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLE3$           |
|  16 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_TABLE1$        |
|  17 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TABLE1$           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

План ПОСЛЕ использования to_date на TABLE2

```
select *
  from TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
 where TABLE1.id = TABLE2.TABLEID
   and TABLE1.id = TABLE3.TABLEID
   and TABLE3.DATAFIELD + 1 > trunc(sysdate)
   and TABLE1.DATAFIELD + 1 > trunc(sysdate)
   and ((to_date(TABLE2.DATAFIELD) = trunc(sysdate)) or (TABLE1.ID = nvl(0, 0)))

-------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1081346625
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name              |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                   |
|   1 |  CONCATENATION                  |                   |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                  |                   |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                 |                   |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                   |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1$           |
|   6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_TABLE1$        |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE2$           |
|   8 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLE2$TABLEID    |
|   9 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN            | TABLE3$TABLEID    |
|  10 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | TABLE3$           |
|  11 |   NESTED LOOPS                  |                   |
|  12 |    NESTED LOOPS                 |                   |
|  13 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                   |
|  14 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLE2$           |
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  15 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1$           |
|  16 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_TABLE1$        |
|  17 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN            | TABLE3$TABLEID    |
|  18 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | TABLE3$           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "_Данное поле проиндексировано_", что за индекс? может function-based?

Comment: Нет, просто индекс. По полю. Поэтому и не могу понять, почему с оберткой в функцию, тем более на поле, работает лучше, чем "напрямую"

Comment: Планы выполнения в вопросе покажите. И как вы понимаете что запрос работает "лучше", какова разницы в времени выполнения. Сколько строк в таблице, какова селективность запросов (кол-во найденных строк), как соотносится count(1) и count(distinct t.field) по таблице

Comment: Это я все к тому, что бывают разные ситуации. Иногда работа по индексу может быть дольше фул скана таблицы. А иногда бывает, что для определенного запроса план выполнения строится 5 секунд а потом за 0.5 секунды выполняется сам запрос.

Comment: @Chubatiy Сравните планы для конкретных запросов. Посмотрите почему они лучше. Может из за того, что индекс перестает использоваться оптимизатор начинает выполнение с другой таблицы, по которой получает меньшую селективность, что сказывается на кол-ве выбираемых на более поздних этапах записей. Или из за применения данного индекса выборка идет сначала их этой таблицы, а последующие подклейки к ней идут по более многоуровневым, менее селективным индексам.

Comment: секунду, добавлю планы в вопрос

Comment: Возможно это именно из-за того, что индекс как раз построен не на функции(function-based). Но если так, то что не так с теми же полями, только формата varchar2?

Comment: просто не вариант использовать такое преобразование, как бы быстро оно не работало, без понимания причин

Comment: @Chubatiy А в планах ДО и ПОСЛЕ - какой из них быстрее. мне почему то кажется что должен быть первый. Но по логике вашего сообщения выходит, что второй. По этой самой дате индекс отдельный построен и тот ли это индекс который в плане `TABLE2$TABLEID` И `table2` в запросе 2 раза, она по каким полям вообще клеится. например только по ID или есть равенство дат из двух таблиц

Comment: Возможно хилая селективность в данном поле, и индекс не используется. Попробуйте также использовать связываемую переменную: 
select * from TABLE t where field = :value

Comment: @Mike так вот получается что по логике первый должен работать шутрее, а получается что второй. Индекс отдельный. Сейчас ещё приложу запросы

Comment: Тут дело вообще не в этом индексе и даже не совсем в этом поле. Из за функций он похоже не может сделать `HASH JOIN` который сам по себе быстрее, но из за этого джоина в первом случае, он начинает делать `FULL TABLE3` внутри `nested loops` что его и просаживает

Comment: @Chubatiy что то вы напутали в именах таблиц. у вас `TABLE1.id = TABLE2.TABLEID` а `table3` по id вообще не клеится. думаю в одном из этих условий все таки table3

Comment: @Mike да, напутал, поправлю, сек. Исправил. Не понял, из-за каких функций не получается слепить hash_join?

Comment: @Chubatiy Я вот вообще пока не пойму, почему эта функция влияет на поведение других таблиц. А что если в `((TABLE2.DATAFIELD = trunc(sysdate)) or (TABLE1.ID = nvl(0, 0)))` table1.ID поменять на table2.id. По логике должно выйти то же, а по плану... интересно изменится ли. И nvl(0,0) это сильно влияло ? зачем так ?

Comment: @Mike заменить нельзя. TABLE1 - главная таблица, на неё все вяжутся(на её примари). Можно заменить TABLE1.ID в этом месте на TABLE2.TABLEID, но это мало что даст. nvl(0,0)  - там сделано так потому, что в качестве параметра может подаваться на вход значение из TABLE.ID. Т.е. этот or написан, чтобы выборка работала и по дате или по значению ID

Comment: @Chubatiy Что значит "главная" в основном условии сказано, что их ID всегда совпадают и никаких left join и `(+)` в запросе не видно. Так вы пробовали сделать там table2, у меня ощущение, что он в таком случае может начать рассматривать OR совершенно иным способом

Comment: @Mike в основном условии указано, что TABLE2 и TABLE3 вяжутся с TABLE1 по полю TABLEID. Но это не означает, что TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID. В условии ((TABLE2.DATAFIELD = trunc(sysdate)) or (TABLE1.ID = nvl(0, 0))) можно заменить лишь TABLE1.ID на TABLE2.TABLEID

Comment: @Chubatiy Ну да, конечно я имел ввиду на `TABLE2.TABLEID`. Хотя уже сомневаюсь что изменит ... Я так понял, что индекс по дате вообще не используется. И что то мне подсказывает, что оракл думает  что по одной дате он найдет очень мало записей. А вот почему он так думает, взяв инфу из статистики индекса или по общей статистике... Из за того, что он думает что данных очень мало он почему то решается на FULL TABLE3, что гробит скорость. А когда стоит to_date он походу не строит предположений о селективности (не решается использовать статистику ?) и идет по tab3 по индексу

Comment: @Mike ну это единственное, что и мне пришло в голову. Только вот почему он так решает, чем служит ему to_date, подсказкой что ли... Вы считаете что такое использование to_date все же допусимо?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33042/discussion-between-chubatiy-and-mike).

Comment: @Chubatiy Нет, не подсказкой. Я думаю он не пытается строить предположений, что выдаст функция на выходе для конкретной даты. Тупо - "не само поле - статистику не юзаем". И интересно, что будет если индекс по дате удалить, если он конечно где то в других местах системы не используется.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33086/discussion-on-question-by-chubatiy------sql-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В таких случаях важно рассматривать весь запрос в целом, а не его отдельные элементы. Потому как изменение предпочтений оптимизатора по одной таблице может приводить к кардинальному изменению его подхода к другим таблицам в этом же запросе.

В данном, конкретном, случае индекс по полю даты был вообще не причем. Oracle и не пытался его использовать. Применение функции `to_date` к полю приводило к тому, что оптимизатор, скорее всего, не использовал статистику по данному полю и предполагал наличие большого количества записей в таблице по заданному условию. Что, в свою очередь, заставляло оптимизатор выбирать более разумный план подклейки других двух таблиц и идти по тем, другим таблицам по индексу.

А в варианте без `to_date` оптимизатор использовал статистику по полю даты, считал, что по конкретной дате он выберет мало данных. А для малого количества данных выбираемых на первом шаге он считал более оптимальным выполнить полное сканирование, без использования индексов по второй таблице, что приводило к росту времени выполнения, т.к. данных оказывалось больше, чем предполагал оптимизатор.

P.S. Из за наличия `OR` в полном запросе оптимизатор шел по пути выполнения двух разных запросов для первой части OR и для второй (которая и была не оптимальной). Ситуация была исправлена заменой условия `OR` таким образом, что бы в нем участвовали только поля одной таблицы.